# ¿Como Validar solo números y pesos en un textbox al escribir y que no deje de funcionar al hacer Postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validación

Como puedo validar con javascript que al escribir en un textbox solo me deje ingresar números y solo valores de pesos (Decimales) y que al realizar otra acción como por ejemplo el clic de un checkbox y realice el postback no me deje de validar.

Lo estoy realizando en asp.net, visual basic

El textbox y el script

> asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSalario" onkeypress="return Enter(this,event)" CssClass="form-control number">

```
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            $('input.number').keyup(function (event) {

                                // skip for arrow keys
                                if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                }

                                $(this).val(function (index, value) {
                                    return value
                                  .replace(/\D/g, "")
                                  .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".")
                                ;
                                });
                            });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Johan, bienvenido a SOes. Tu pregunta es clara y especifica, pero no muestra ningun esfuerzo de tu parte. Que has intentando? Podrias mostrarnos en que parte de tu codigo tienes dificultades?

Comment: Vale tienes razón, pues más que todo tengo problema al realizar el postback, al realizar el postback deja de funcionar.

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSalario" onkeypress="return Enter(this, event)" CssClass="form-control number"></asp:TextBox>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $('input.number').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
$(this).val(function (index, value) {
   return value
   .replace(/\D/g, "")
   .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, "."); });});</script>

Answer (score 1):

Creo que ya encontré la respuesta a mi problema y lo comparto por si alguno más cuenta con el mismo inconveniente

la cuestión es la siguiente, en un div que se encuentre por fuera del UpdatePanel se pone ID="contenedor" y en el javascript se encierra con la siguiente linea de código

$("#contenedor").on("keyup", "input.number", function(event){...}

El "on" permite durante el postback, que el contenedor que dentro tenga esos controles sobreviva al postback.

```
<div class="row"  id="contenedor">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>  
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSalario" onkeypress="return Enter(this, event)" CssClass="form-control number"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

$<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#contenedor").on("keyup", "input.number", function(event){
   $('input.number').keyup(function (event) {
     if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

       $(this).val(function (index, value) {
         return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ".");
         });
       });
     });
</script>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Aquí la explicación más exacta.

Click https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/cacc8a91-4166-45ec-a085-380960b57dd6/javascript-deja-de-funcionar-cuando-la-pagina-hace-postback?forum=netfxwebes